# Python Attributes Performance

Tags: python, performance

I have a general questions to the performance of python.

If I "give" a method a variable, class or similar, does the size (data, methods...) of this object affect the speed of the program?

```
def function(foo):
    pass

function(superHeavyObject)
function(superLightObject)
```

And: is a big dictionary/list slower than a small?

```
dict1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
dict1["c"]

dict2 = {"a": 1, "b":2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5 "f": 6, "g": 7, "h": 8, ...}
dict2["c"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? Whether accessing a big dict is slower than a small dict, or whether passing a large object into a method is slower? Also, did you try to `timeit`?

Comment: Please keep it to **one** question at a time. No, the size of the object doesn't affect how fast you can pass it around. References are just references, whatever the size of the object they point to. Dictionaries have a O(1) lookup, so it doesn't matter how big they are, the key lookup takes constant time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "one question at a time" I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the size of the object doesn't affect how fast you can pass it around. References are just references, whatever the size of the object they point to.

Dictionaries normally have an average O(1) lookup, so it doesn't matter how big they are, the key lookup takes constant time. See [*Time Complexity* in the Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Only if you were to produce massively colliding keys (keys that all hash to the same slot) would you run into the theoretical worst case of O(n) lookups. In practice this doesn't happen. Security researchers did [make use of this theoretical possibility](http://bugs.python.org/issue13703) to show how you could DoS a Python program, but recent Python releases have mitigated this by adding a random component to hashes.

Comment: Great, thanks.
The site is a bit hard to read for me, so I'm not sure if it answers this question too: Needs `list[2][3][4]` more time than `list[3]`?

Comment: Yes, because there are 3 indexing operations instead if just one. Realistically it won't make much difference.

Comment: Depends on the situation. Thanks.